# Write ASP.NET aspx page output to server-side disk

Tags: asp.net

I am writing an application which produces reports.  I want to save the generated html server side to the disk for another application to use.

The response objects only expose streams for writing data.  I need to read the data from the response and write it to disk.

Is there a more graceful way of doing this than creating a front-end which receives the user request, programattically makes a separate report http request, saves the response to disk and writes it to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Filter` property of the `HttpResponse`.

something like:

```
YourFilterStream filter = new YourFilterStream(response.Filter);
response.Filter = filter;
```